# How to display data in a table?

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to display the data that comes to me from the server as an array of objects. The number of objects may vary.
For example -

```
{"RowNumber":1,"WalletName":"Elsom","PayerPhoneNumber":"996555121212","CreatedDate":"2022-06-10T10:52:00","Amount":50.2,"CurrencyCode":"KGS"},
{"RowNumber":2,"WalletName":"O!","PayerPhoneNumber":"996555131313","CreatedDate":"2022-06-09T22:12:00","Amount":122.3,"CurrencyCode":"KGS"},
```

You need to display them in the form of a table, how to do this - I don’t understand at all, I processed the response from the server. I made a cycle, but how can I display it on the screen with such a code structure? -

```
class Report extends StatelessWidget {
  var ressultat = json.decode(MyApp.resultat)['Transactions']; //here is an array of objects!!!!!

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Center(
            child: , //HERE HERE HERE
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And where can I put the loop? -

```
var ress = json.decode(MyApp.resultat)['Transactions'];
                        print(ress[5]['Amount']);
                        for (int i = 0; i <= ress.length; i++) {
                          print(ress[i]);
                        }
```

Comment: Have you tried using the json_serializable and json_annotation packages to easily create model classes so you can display the data accordily?

Comment: No, I'm still new to the world of programming

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when wanting to see what was returning from a databse on the screen and slapped this together. It's by no means pretty but it does the job, just pass in a Map<String, dynamic> and a String title.

```
class Tabler extends StatelessWidget {
  const Tabler({Key? key, required this.dataMap, required this.title})
      : super(key: key);
  final Map<String, dynamic> dataMap;
  final String title;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Widget> dataColumns = [];
    for (var v in dataMap.values) {
      dataColumns.add(_TablerBlock(
        dataBlock: v,
      ));
    }
    return DefaultTextStyle(
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25, color: Colors.black),
        child: Container(
            width: 400,
            child: Column(children: <Widget>[
              Text(dataMap.toString()),
              Text(title),
              SizedBox(height: 20),
              ...dataColumns
            ])));
  }
}

class _TablerBlock extends StatelessWidget {
  const _TablerBlock({Key? key, required this.dataBlock}) : super(key: key);
  final dynamic dataBlock;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Widget> block = [];
    if (dataBlock is Map<String, dynamic>) {
      for (var v in dataBlock.entries) {
        block.add(_TablerRow(
          dataRow: [v.key, v.value],
        ));
      }
    }
    return Container(
        child: Column(children: <Widget>[
      ...block,
    ]));
  }
}

class _TablerRow extends StatelessWidget {
  const _TablerRow({Key? key, required this.dataRow}) : super(key: key);
  final List<dynamic> dataRow;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
      children: [
        Text(dataRow[0].toString() + ': '),
        Text(dataRow[1].toString()),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Use it by calling

```
Center(
  child: Tabler(dataMap: yourMap, title: 'title');
)
```

Note that it only works for a single Map.